# Unable to focus input field in HTML page

Tags: html, css, forms

I am unable to select the input fields in the form by clicking.But I can select using Tab.I am pasting the source code.

If I paste it outside all divs.I am able to select the input elements.

```
#body{
max-width:1366px;#border:5px dotted black;
position:relative;
top:75px;
z-index:-1;
margin:auto;
overflow:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
*{
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
    
}

    
<html>
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="new.css">
<body >
<div id=main_div width=100%>
<div id=body>
<div id=empty>
<form method=get  action=login.php>
Username:
<input type=text name=uname value="">
Password:
<input type=password name=pass value="">
<center><input type=Submit value="Log in" name=submit><center>
</form>
</div>
<div id=big>
<div id=mini>
</div>
<div id=log>
</div>
<div id=mini>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a z-index: -1 on your #body id remove it and it works.
I will highly recommend you check an HTML CSS tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your html structure is incorrect

remove negative `z-index:-1` from `#body`
it should work for you

Answer (score 0):

U cannot select the textfields because of the "z-index: -1"